# How can I get a substring from position N to the last char in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, substring

I'd like to get a substring from a string from position N to the end of the string.

What's the way to do it in Ruby?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Just slice the string like:

```
string[N..-1]
```

Comment: how about not specifying one of the ranges, possible?

Comment: Yes you can; string[5..7] for example would give you from index 5 to 7. So if your string is "Tomatoes are funny fruits" you'd get "oes".

Answer (score 1):

As of Ruby 2.6, you can use [endless range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Range.html#class-Range-label-Endless+Ranges) syntax for this:

```
string[N..]
```

where N is the start index. (No need to specify a `-1` for the end index.)

For example:

```
'abcdefghij'[3..]  # Evaluates to 'defghij'
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can use the size :
    str[N,str.size-1]

Comment: This is not the Ruby way. It complicates things unnecessarily, when using the range N..-1 'just works'