# Ruby idiom for substring from index until end of string

Tags: ruby, string, substring, slice, idioms

Just wondering if there's a Ruby idiom for extracting a substring from an index until the end of the string. I know of `str[index..-1]` which works by passing in a range object to the `String`'s `[]` method but it's a little clunky. In python, for example, you could write `str[index:]` which would implicitly get you the rest of the string.

Example:

```
s = "hello world"
s[6..-1] # <-- "world"
```

Is there anything nicer than `s[6..-1]`?

Comment: I think explicity is nicer than implicity in this case.

Comment: @Flauwekeul Why is Range a clunk in that respect?

Comment: What do you mean with clunk?

Comment: @Flauwekeul Sorry, I mixed up you with owner of this question.

Comment: I think it's clunky just because the -1 index isn't super intuitive.

Comment: It's also clunky because `6..-1` is an empty range. :-/ `s[0..5]` can be understood as `(0..5).map{|i| s[i]}.join` but `(6..-1).map{|i| s[i]}.join` is an empty string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a substring from position N to the last char in Ruby 1.8.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944804/how-can-i-get-a-substring-from-position-n-to-the-last-char-in-ruby-1-8-7)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it isn't.

It seems that `Range` is better way to do it.

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify? You think ```Range``` (the way I have in the  question) is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 12):

Ruby 2.6 introduced [endless ranges](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Range.html#class-Range-label-Endless+Ranges), which basically remove the need to have to specify the end index. In your case, you can do:

```
s = "hello world"
s[6..]
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is 'nicer' if you wish. You can extend ruby String class and then use this method into your code. For example:

```
class String
  def last num
    self[-num..-1]
  end
end
```

And then:

```
s = "hello world"
p s.last(6)
```

Comment: OP didn't request how to get the last X characters. They asked how to get characters from X to the end of the string

Answer (score 5):

To get the string from a range:

```
s = 'hello world'
s[5..s.length - 1] # world
```

However, if you just want to get the last word:

```
'hello world'.split(' ').last # world
```

Comment: It should be `s[5..s.length - 1]`

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the `String` class. Not sure if it's a ruby idiom though:

```
class String
  def last(n)
    self[(self.length - n)..-1]
  end
end
```

Comment: OP wants the last characters starting from `n`. Not the last `n` characters.

Answer (score 2):

Rails' `activesupport` library (which can be installed as a gem independent of Rails) adds a `from` method to strings:

```
> s = "hello world"
"hello world"
> s.from(6)
"world"
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-from